# v-calendar question, how to disable dates based on dates in an object's arraylist

Tags: javascript, vue.js, calendar, vuex, vcalendar

i just started to code, and right now we are using v-calendar.io in our airbnb project and we need to disable dates based on a listing's unavailable date arraylist in the backend.

```
<v-date-picker
  class="date-picker"
  v-model="date"
  :disabled-dates="[new Date(2021, 9, 10)]"
  color="blue"
  is-range
/>
```

So putting dates in the :disabled-dates works, but how do i do to make it function based on the arraylist instead of hard coded preset dates? ( I've learnt how to fetch data from backend, but i don't know how to code so the :disabled-dates take those info )

Comment: What's in your `script` tag? Are you using the `computed` or `data` property?

Comment: thank you for your reply, i am not using any computed right now, purely using the code vcalendar provided on their site. <script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      range: {
        start: new Date(2020, 0, 1),
        end: new Date(2020, 0, 5),
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your array of dates into Vue components data:

```
data: () => ({
   disabledDays: [] // later populated from API call
})
```

Then you can do:

```
<v-date-picker
  class="date-picker"
  v-model="date"
  :disabled-dates="disabledDays" /*not hardcoded*/
  color="blue"
  is-range
/>
```

---

Once you receive date strings from backend, you can convert them into date objects like:

```
this.disabledDays = response.disabledDates.map(string => new Date(string))`
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, i'm a bit confused, doesn't it need to be like vcalendar's code [New Date()] something? Is there any required date format when we save our arraylist in backend?

Comment: Your backend would be saving and returning data format in [ISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) format, once you receive these strings in frontend, you can convert them to actual date objects like `this.disabledDays = response.dateStringsArrayFromBackend.map(string => new Date(string))`

Comment: Sorry, i'm sure you know this stuff, but I'm really new to coding so i can't really understand the response.dateStringsArrayFromBackend.map(string => new Date(string)) part, i will show your answer to my group and we will see what we get out of it. thank you for the help

Comment: Could you please tell me How can i disable all past dates from today ?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a snippet to show you things simpler. I put a `setTimeout` in `mounted` to simulate a request from the server, and after 1 second, the response will come from the server and fill the `disable_dates` with date objects.

I used the simplest way to map the strings to the date objects, and you can also use `map` or normal `for` to achieve this goal.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    date: null,
    disable_dates: [],

  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let string_dates_from_srver = ['2021-05-05', '2021-05-08']
      string_dates_from_srver.forEach((item) => {
        this.disable_dates.push(new Date(item))
      })
    }, 1000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/v-calendar@2.3.0/lib/v-calendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/v-calendar@2.3.0/lib/v-calendar.umd.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'>

  <v-date-picker class="date-picker" v-model="date" :disabled-dates="disable_dates" color="blue" is-range></v-date-picker>

  {{date}}
</div>
```